# Scanner is creating a NoSuchElementException error, and I can't figure out why

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I was given the assignment to make a table of hurricanes over the Atlantic, and their wind speed, pressure, etc. and I was testing it to make sure that the scanner inFile was working but kept getting an error

I have tried throws Exception, throws NoSuchElementException, changing the ints to Strings(not sure why I thought this would work)

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File data = new File("C:\\Users\\zenno\\OneDrive\\Documents\\School\\Hurricane Data\\hurcdata2.txt");
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner (data);


        int length = 0;
        while (inFile.hasNextLine()){
            length++;
            inFile.nextLine();
        }
        int[] year = new int[length];
        String[] month = new String[length];
        int[] pressure = new int[length];
        int[] speed = new int[length];
        String[] name = new String[length];


        for(int n = 0; n <= length; n++){
            year[n] = inFile.nextInt();
            month[n] = inFile.next();
            pressure[n] = inFile.nextInt();
            speed[n] = inFile.nextInt();
            name[n] = inFile.next();

            System.out.println(year[n] + "  " + month[n] + "  " + pressure[n] + "  " + speed[n] + "  " + name[n]);

        }



    }

}
```

It should be printing out the int's and strings, but I am getting this eror instead

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

Line 25 is:

```java
            year[n] = inFile.nextInt();
```

Any help as to what my mistake was would be appreciated

Comment: What do you think your `while` loop does? How does it affect `inFile` Scanner, what is its state after it?

Comment: I didn't think of that. Would adding a second scanner of the same file be a good way to fix it, or is there a better method?

Comment: Solution depends on what you want to achieve which is not clear here. Usually we don't need to iterate over file twice. If we want to store its data we are using resizable structure like List. OR we can handle all data from file on-the-fly (like you are doing in your second loop, but instead of taking data from array print them directly from scanner. Also you are having many arrays of same size. Usually if we have `String[] names, String[] addresses, int[] ages` it means we probably should have one class like `class Person{ String name; String address; int age;}` and `Person[] people` instead.

Comment: Or don't use arrays at all, Lists are usually more useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scanner is pointing to the last line of the file because of while loop and in the same line you are trying to read

```
year[n] = inFile.nextInt();
```

which is causing exception because there is no element where the scanner is pointing.